# Extracting different size rectangles from image using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Extracting different size rectangles from image using opencv does not work correctly
It doesn't give us patches of all character, just give one patch, but I want patches of all characters

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( "1a.bmp" );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
       minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
      //circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
  for(int i = 0; i < boundRect.size(); i++)
{
     Mat patch = src(boundRect[i]);
     //Do whatever you want with the patch (imshow, imwrite,...)
     imshow("Patch",patch);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have to extract the rectangles, because you already have them in your `vector<Rect> boundRect`. 
If you want to get patches of the image that contain the rectangles/characters, you just need to cut them out:

```
stringstream ss;
for(int i = 0; i < boundRect.size(); i++)
{
     ss>>"Patch ">>i;
     Mat patch = src(boundRect[i]);
     //Do whatever you want with the patch (imshow, imwrite,...)
     imshow(ss.str(), patch);
     ss.str("");
}
```

Comment: thanks @dennis It work correctly, but it cut out just one rectangle. actually I want patches of all characters.

Comment: It should cut out every patch, if you iterate over your rectangles. What is the size of `boundRect`? Really 1?

Comment: size of boundRect is not 1, it depends, from where our character start and where it end.... actually I'm working on ocr. so I need patches of every character. when I iterate it our my rectangles it give me out just 1 pactch!

Comment: Maybe you could share your code, where you iterate over the rectangles and cut them out

Comment: I have edit above code, please refer this code, for obtaining patch of each character, based on contours...thanks

Comment: It only shows the last rectangle/character in the window "Patch". If you want to show all patches, you need as much windows as the amount of charaters, so you can do this to identify your windows (see my edit).

Comment: That's good ;) So you can accept my answer, if it works for you correctly.

Comment: yup I accepted your answer... can you tell me! how I get whole line of character rather than getting single character?  –

Comment: Two ideas: 1. You could try morphologic closing (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) after thresholding with a structuring element that is wider than high (20x2?), so characters next to each other are connected. 2 idea: Check the positions of your rectangles and collect rectangles that have the (almost) same y-position. These approaches assume that the lines are parallel to your x-axis of your image (like the image you posted)

Comment: if I use idea 1, then where I will use above(your edited patches code)? in Morphology_Operations function? if so then what will I use instead of boundRect in that code?

Comment: You have to use it after threshold(...) and before findContours(...) in your code. You don't have to change anything else in the code.

Comment: thanks a lot @dennis now it properly working, giving me patches of connected characters.

Answer (score 0):

> @user, you can also try this in opencv documentation

```
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contours = 0;
cvFindContours( img, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
CV_RETR_LIST , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cvPoint(0,0) );
for( CvSeq* c=contours; c!=NULL; c=c->h_next)
{
CvRect Rects = cvBoundingRect( c );
}
```

> @dennis i also need to extract line. guide me also